# autohotkey loop through list

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I am attempting to loop through the list in VarX and send the keystrokes requested until the list is done. Right now it seems to jumble up and not run the commands correctly in order. any ideas of what I have wrong? it should run like this:

```
ctrl f
48306237
enter
tab tab tab tab enter
shift space
ctrl -
```

then repeat with the next number...

```
^!G::

VarX=

(
48306237
48306642
48303423
48303612
48303797
)

loop, parse, VarX, `n,`r

{

Send, ^f
Send, %VarX%
Send, {enter}
Send, {tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{enter}
Send, +{space}
Send, ^-
return

}

return
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is a double post? Please delete one of your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [autohotkey loop through txt and send each line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092882/autohotkey-loop-through-txt-and-send-each-line)